# What are MLM and NSP models actually used for after they've been trained?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, bert, language-model

I am a Python programmer working with deep learning nets and I have recently built my own language models as well as I have fine-tuned popular models like BERT. MY question is - after these models have been successfully trained, what are they used for? I understand that masked-language models can predict what the masked word is, but what is the point? What is a real-world application of this model? The same question goes for next-sentence prediction models - what is a real-world application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally fine-tune pre-trained masked language models in a different "downstream" task, e.g. text classification.

MLM and NSP pre-training is not an end, but just a means to profit from a large amount of unlabeled data in your supervised learning problem.